# Finding the maximum value in a column using GQL

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, max, gql

How do I find the maximum value in a particular column of a table in the GAE datastore using GQL?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To get the max you using GQL, you could do this:

```
max_x = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM MyModel ORDER BY x DESC").get().x
```

You could use this syntactically shorter but equivalent approach:

```
max_x = MyModel.all().order('-x').get().x
```